# What happened to the “too old” message?

Tags: bug, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I just voted to close [this two-year-old question](https://superuser.com/q/352818/150988)
because I believed that it was off-topic for Super User,
and that it belonged on another site in the Stack Exchange network. 
However, I was not given that sub-option. 
I’m pretty sure that, until the recent revision of the VTC reasons
(when “Not a Real Question” was abolished),
there was a message saying that questions over a certain age
were ineligible for migration. 
The policy seems to be unchanged, but the message is gone,
leaving the prospective close-voter looking in vain for the button he wants to use.

Please restore the “too old to migrate” message. 
(Or cancel the “too old” policy; just be consistent.)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the specific question?

Comment: Hm. Confirmed that there's no migration-disabled notice. Please don't say in comments "should be asked on _site_" though. This encourages cross-posting.

Comment: @nhinkle: I didn’t (or, at least, I didn’t mean to). I clicked on “Close”; under “Why should this question be closed?”, I clicked on “off-topic because…”; and, under “Closing > Off-Topic”, I clicked on “Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)” and filled in the “Comment” box. I expected that to be treated as a custom close reason that would be visible only to those >3000 users who can cast Close votes. But, even as it is, who’s going to see it except for people who find it through the Close Review queue (or this MSU question)? (It is a two-year-old question, after all.)

Comment: @nhinkle Another question: [here](http://superuser.com/questions/84661/delete-data-for-specific-iphone-app). Voted to close as Off Topic, but there was no Migration message, so I flagged instead.

Comment: @nhinkle: P.S. My exact words were “This question belongs on webapps.stackexchange.com.” -- which is copied from the “This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network” (i.e., migration) option on the “Closing > Off-Topic” menu for questions that aren’t too old to be migrated.

Comment: @Scott when using the close > off topic menu, there's a potential for the question to get migrated. If you leave a comment, the user might misinterpret it. We discourage people from leaving any sort of comment that says "this question belongs on" unless it's accompanied by a qualifier that it'll be moved automatically for them if necessary.

Comment: OK, back over here. [You say](http://meta.superuser.com/a/7437/150988) that the author of a question “should be aware of _why_ their question is being closed.” Well, then, if a question that’s young enough to migrate gets close votes that say “Off-Topic” > “This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network”, can’t the author get to the “Closing > Off-Topic” window that says “This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network” and the “Closing > Off-Topic > Migration” window that says “belongs on ______”?